# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently updated my routes to pass in `token` for `params[:id]` on my show and copy_order actions. However, in my index, I have the following view which is creating an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Hash):
<td><%= link_to("#{order.merchant.name} - #{pluralize(order.item_count, 'Item')}", order_path(order))%></td>
```

_order.html.erb (partial for show)

```
<tr>
  <td><%= order.format_order_time(order.to_local_timezone(order.created_at)) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to("#{order.merchant.name} - #{pluralize(order.item_count, 'Item')}", order_path(order.token))%></td>
  <td><%= number_to_currency(order.total_cost) %></td>
  <td>
    <% if order.cart_users.count == 1 %>
      <%= form_tag copy_order_order_path(order), method: :post do |f| %>
        <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-primary') do %>
          Add Order To Cart
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      Shared Order
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :orders, only: [:index]
resources :orders, only: [:show, :copy_order], params: :token do
  post 'copy_order', to: 'orders#copy_order', on: :member
end
```

I have a feeling it is because my paths and the arguments I am passing into them are messed up.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please share the error log in the question.

Comment: @KirtiThorat what do you mean? I updated my question with the line that it references.

Comment: You're saying "it's creating an error". What error?

Comment: @JTG ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failboat. The error was in my routes.

```
resources :orders, only: [:show, :copy_order], params: :token do
  post 'copy_order', to: 'orders#copy_order', on: :member
end
```

Instead of `params: :token`, it should be `param: :token`.

Comment: Had the same problem. The weird part is that in development everything worked like a charm, and then suddenly on prod it fails.. Your post saved my life! Thanks

Comment: This was awhile ago - glad it helped! :D